# Why is argument empty in docker?

Tags: docker

When I built docker I have argument that is empty.

```
ARG ENV=prod
RUN echo ${ENV} // this works very good it show right

CMD /my-project -env ${ENV} this ENV is empty it show empty
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ARG is for building your docker image.  ENV is what you want for a running container.

CMD is executed when your container is run.

https://vsupalov.com/docker-arg-vs-env/

```
ENV ENV prod
```

Might suggest changing your name to something that isn't a Dockerfile keyword though.

Comment: More detailed info.  https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/dockerfile_best-practices/#env